# Angular HTTP Post observable only works the first time it is called

Tags: angular, post, observable

On my front end web page there is a button to allow user submit data on click. User may submit the data **multiple times** through the same restful api. I use **http.post** method in angular to post the data but it only works for the first time user click submit.

```js
onClick() {
   //**code in here executed every time user click submit button**.
  this. subscription = this.http.post<any>("url",data,httpOptions).subscribe(
    //**code inside here only executed once. The next time user click submit button, it won't trigger execution**.
  );
}
```

How can I make the post works every time user click submit button? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this code inside the function called by the (click) event of the button? Could you post it?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. Thank you.

Comment: Do you get some error message in the console? Code snippet you posted should work for multiple button clicks. Every time a new post request is sent to the rest api.

Comment: just make sure onClick() function  is called every time by adding console.log. If that works this may be related to cache and for post calls we may need to add headers.  headersAdditional = < Headers > headers.headers;
headersAdditional.append('Cache-control', 'no-cache');
headersAdditional.append('Cache-control', 'no-store');
headersAdditional.append('Expires', '0');
headersAdditional.append('Pragma', 'no-cache');
this._http.post(url, data, {
    headers: headersAdditional
})

Comment: You'll need to supply

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to supply the code for before 'this.subscription' and inside.. as we can only guess otherwise. If you can supply the HTML for the button also it may highlight the issue.

I have tried using the below and I have no issues:

```js
onClick() {
    //**code in here executed every time user click submit button**.
    this.subscription = this.http.post<any>("https://www.google.com", {}, {}).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
}
```

```html
<button (click)="onClick()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Problem solved. The code inside http post did get called. It takes 20 seconds for back-end to return the data so it doesn't get response immediately. I put some loading effect on the web page to indicate visually it is waiting for the back end response. But I forgot to reset the state of loading when resubmit so there is no loading effect on the web page the second time I submit. So it gives me an impression that the post is not working. Thank you.

Comment: Google Chrome's 'Developer Tools' > 'Network' tab is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember the Angular's design pattern: you have the components and services to manage your project. The service file has a injectable anotation.

Second: Is recommended have a method to call the requisitions. Maybe it could be the solution, because the angular lost the reference.